# Threads are in blocked state when JMeter script is executed [non-gui mode]

Tags: jmeter, thread-dump

I am running the JMeter script with 100 RPS/TPS using **Throughput Shaping Timer** on Linux VM using Non-GUI mode, as I am not able to reach the desired TPS/RPS with enough RAM and CPU resource available.

I took the ThreadDump and saw that 195 Threads out of 200 Threads are in Blocked State. Thread Dump Analysis is available on:

[Thread Dump Analysis](https://fastthread.io/my-thread-report.jsp?p=c2hhcmVkLzIwMjIvMDkvMjMvdGhyZWFkRHVtcF9MaW51eF8yM1NlcC50ZHVtcC0tOC00Ni0zNg==&)

This is the API Script which needs dynamic headers generation before each Request is executed. Dynamic headers are as follows:

1. contentMD5 - MD5 hash of request body
2. client - clientTypeAPP
3. nonce - unique current timestamp
4. apikey - sha512Hmac of the string generated by concatenating Methods, body, path, md5 etc.

The above headers are generated using the **JSR223 Pre Processor**. The generated headers are also removed using **JSR223 Post Processor** after Sampler execution.

Answer (score 0):

The thread dump shows that the problem is with your JSR223 Test Elements, most probably there is an issue with your Groovy code and most probably you're inlining [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) there

1. Make sure to remove all occurrences of calls to functions or variables from the code
2. Try using script files rather than putting your code into JSR223 test elements

   [image]
3. Use a [profiler tool](https://www.baeldung.com/java-profilers) to get to the bottom of your code issues
4. If you hit the limits of the Groovy scripting engine performance consider either [moving your custom code logic into a JMeter Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugin-development) or switching to [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)